# Display unicode fractions Python

Tags: python, unicode, fractions

I would like to display fractions in a certain format and I don't know actually how it's possible in Python.
I have as input a decimal:

```
>>> decimal = 0.5
```

and I would like to display it in fraction format. For the moment I'm using Fraction library:

```
>>> f = Fraction(decimal)
>>> print f
>>> 1/2
```

But I would like to display the fraction with this format: `½`

Is there any way I can do that easily?

Comment: Given that such characters only exist for a handful of fractions, that doesn't seem like it would be very useful.

Comment: There are about 15 fractions which have a unicode representation. It's probably best to put those in a defaultdict with Fraction as the default factory function.

Comment: Also note that [`unicodedata.numeric`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.numeric) will tell you the numeric value of a fraction symbol. E.g. `unicodedata.numeric(unicodedata.lookup('VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER')) == 0.25`. But then again this may be of limited usefulness because comparing floats for equality is tricky.